# C++11 initializer_list constructor with header and cpp file for custom vector class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constructor, initializer-list

I'm doing a school project where I am to construct a custom vector class.
And the class should be able to initialize vectors in a few different ways.
I've got stuck with this initializer_list initialization of the vector.

The only values wich are allowed as elements are unsigned int.

header

```
#include <initializer_list>
class myvec {
private:
    unsigned int *arr; //pointer to array
    std::size_t n; //size of myvec
public:
    myvec(); // Default contructor
    myvec(std::size_t size); // Creating a vec with # of element as size
    myvec(const myvec&); // Copy constructor
    myvec(const initializer_list<unsigned int>& list);
```

cpp

```
#include "myvec.h"
#include <initializer_list>

myvec::myvec() {
    arr = new unsigned int[0];
    n = 0;
}

myvec::myvec(std::size_t size) {
    arr = new unsigned int[size];
    n = size;
}

myvec::myvec(const myvec& vec) {
    arr = new unsigned int[vec.n];
    n = vec.n;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.n; i++) {
        arr[i]=vec.arr[i];
    }
}

myvec::myvec(const std::initializer_list<unsigned int> list) {

}
```

What I don't understand is how the constructor should be written for it to work? Been trying to find answers on internet for a long time without success.

I want to call the initializer_list constructor from another c++ file as
test.cpp

```
myvec a = {1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: Make 1-argument-ctors `explicit` unless you know why not.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` does not need to be passed by reference. It is a strange type that stores a reference to a temporary array, and is typically passed by value.

Comment: also the declaration and the definition do not match

Comment: Unrelated: and i never get fuzzies when I see the likes of : `arr = new unsigned int[0];`

Comment: @WhozCraig: You mean he should invest in a few seconds reading of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are passing the [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) argument by value (and you can, it is lightweight), you could do something like:

```
myvec(std::initializer_list<unsigned int> l) : myvec(l.size()) {
  std::copy(std::begin(l), std::end(l), arr);
}
```

That is, you initialize your internal array with the `size()` of the list, and you iterate over it with [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin2) and [`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/end) to copy over its elements.

Comment: In the header file I write definition as // myvec(initializer_list<unsigned int> list) : myvec(list.size()); // and in the cpp file myvec::myvec(std::initializer_list<unsigned int> list) : myvec(list.size()) {
 std::copy(std::being(list), std::end(list), arr);
}

Comment: No. Just write `myvec(initializer_list<unsigned int> list)` . the members initialization goes into the definition (the cpp in your case)

Comment: ok so in header I have myvec(initializer_list<unsigned int> list); and the rest is the same. But i get error in compile with error: expected ')' before '<' token. on the line in the header file and error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token. on the line in the cpp file myvec::myvec. Sorry but don't know how to write the code in grey background :/

Comment: You need `#include <initializer_list>` in your header (use backticks to format the code in your comments). You will also need `#include <algorithm>` in the cpp for `std::copy`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Last comment :)  : You might miss and `std::`, check a working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/045afe6b70f928b7)

Comment: I don't know what's happening but the compiler is still giving errors even though it should be working now. I get ``error: expected ')' before '<' token`` in the .h file at ``myvec(initializer_list<unsigned int> list)``

Comment: Ok the problem was that the school computer is default to an older compiler that couldn't handle the code. Fixed it and it works now. Thanks for all the help =)

Answer (score 2):

[`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) has 3 member functions:

- [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size)
- [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin)
- [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/end)

And that's all you need.