# Is it possible to initialize a vector in C++ like in Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, vector, operator-overloading, initializer-list

In Matlab, you can initialize vectors like this:

```
>> a = 3;
>> b = 4.6;
>> c = [2, 1.3, a, b]

c =

    2.0000    1.3000    3.0000    4.6000
```

I'd like to use a similar syntax in C++. Specifically, I have my own vector class Vec:

```
class Vec {
public:
    unsigned N; //number of elements
    double* e; //array of elements
    Vec(unsigned); //constructor
    ~Vec(void); //destructor
    Vec(const Vec&); //copy constructor
    Vec& operator=(const Vec&); //copy assignment operator
};
```

And I'd like to initialize it like this:

```
Vec v;
int a = 3;
double b = 4.6;

v = {2, 1.3, a, b}; //a is converted from int to double

std::cout << "N = " << v.N << std::endl;
std::cout << "v = [" << v.e[0] << ", " << v.e[1] << ", "
          << v.e[2] << ", " << v.e[3] << "]" << std::endl;
```

So that it would print:

```
N = 4
v = [2, 1.3, 3, 4.6]
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

---

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260331/c11-initializer-list-constructor-with-header-and-cpp-file-for-custom-vector-cl), but the answer is about the copy constructor, not the copy assignment operator.

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: You can use an `initializer_list`, `std::vector` already allows this syntax. [Demo](http://ideone.com/CjZ65w)

Comment: I know about `initializer_list`, but still don't know how to do that. I tried `Vec& operator=(const initializer_list<double>);` and a bunch of other stuff and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `std::vector`.

If you must write it yourself with arrays, probably the easiest way is to first write an initializer list constructor as described in the question you linked to:

```
Vec(unsigned size) : N(size), e(new double[size]) {}

Vec(std::initializer_list<double> l) : Vec(l.size()) {
  std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), e);
}
```

Then write a no-throw `swap`:

```
void swap(Vec& rhs) noexcept {
  std::swap(e, rhs.e);
  std::swap(N, rhs.N);
}
```

and finally, a standard assignment operator:

```
Vec& operator=(Vec rhs) {
  swap(rhs);
  return *this;
}
```

Then it will convert the `initializer_list` to a `Vec` using the initializer list constructor and then assign using the assignment operator.

But seriously, just use `std::vector`.